# Docker: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"java\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have a Java Spring Boot app which works with a Postgres database. I want to use Docker for both of them. Initially, I created a docker-compose.yml file as given below:

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  postgres:
    restart: always
    container_name: sample_db
    image: postgres:10.4
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
         - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
         - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
         - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
# APP**
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/test
    expose:
      - '8080'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

Then,inside the application.properties file I defined the following properties.

```
server.port=8080
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.enabled=true

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: true
```

Also,I created a Dockerfile in my project directory, which looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
RUN mkdir -p /app/
RUN mkdir -p /app/logs/
COPY target/household-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar
FROM postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB testdb
COPY schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app/app.jar"]
```

I issued these commands and ended up in the error as given below.

**mvn clean package
docker build ./ -t springbootapp

docker-compose up**

```
ERROR: for household-appliances_web_1  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"java\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"java\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

**Kindly anyone help on this!**

Comment: You seem to have the wrong permissions. Try to run docker-compose as sudo

Comment: You are trying to launch an executable that is linked with Oracle client. You must be doing something fundamental wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I had this error when setting up a Rails appliation for Docker:

My `docker-entrypoint.sh` file was placed in the **root** folder of my application with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -e production
```

And in my Dockerfile, I defined my entrypoint command this way:

```
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

But I was getting the error below when I ran the `docker-compose up command`:

> ERROR: for app  Cannot start service app: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "docker-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $
> PATH": unknown

**Here's how I fixed it**:

Specify an actual path for the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file, that is instead of:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

use

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

This tells docker that the `docker-entrypoint.sh` file is located in the **root** folder of your application, you could also specify a different path if the path to your `docker-entrypoint.sh` is different, but ensure you do not miss out on the `./` prefix to your `docker-entrypoint.sh` file path definition.

So mine looked like this afterwards:

```
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 2):

`application.properties` file content is irrelevant to question, so you can remove it.
Lets look to your Dockerfile, I will remove irrelevant code

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY target/household-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar

FROM postgres
COPY schema.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app/app.jar"]
```

So you are using multistage building, you just copying file from host to first stage.
As final stage you are using `postgres` image and telling to set `ENTRYPOINT` to `java`, but java does not exists in the postgres image.

What you should change:

You should have postgres containe separated from java container like you have it in `docker-compose.yml` file and second suggestion use `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT`.
Your final Dockerfile should be

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY target/household-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/app.jar
CMD ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app/app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `FROM postgres` line creates a second image (it is a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)) that is based on the PostgreSQL database server.  Everything above that line is effectively ignored.  So your final image is running a second database, and not a JVM.

You don't need this line, and you don't need to extend the database server to run a client.  You can delete this line, and the application will start up.

You'll also have to separately get that schema file into the database container. Just bind-mounting the file in `volumes:` in the `docker-compose.yml` file is an easy path.  If you have a database migration system in your application, running migrations on startup will be a more robust approach.

Comment: I think this is real reason of this issue, thank you.